I want to reference a mongodb subdocumnent with a subdocument in the same array. I do not want to store categories in a separate document
I want to reference a mongodb subdocumnent with a subdocument in the same array. I do not want to store categories in a separate document.
const CategorySchema = new Schema(
      {
        name: { type: String, required: true },
        description: { type: String },
        parent: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "CategorySchema" }, // Reference to CategorySchema 
        level: { type: Number, default: 0 },
      },
      { timestamps: true }
    );
    
    const StoreSchema = new Schema(
      {
        name: { type: String, required: true },
        categories: [CategorySchema],
      },
      { timestamps: true }
    );
    
    const Store = mongoose.model("Store", StoreSchema);
    
    module.exports = Store;


Look at the examples in https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html.  The string passed to ref should be the name of the model.  CategorySchema is a local variable, not a name.
